# How to install Ruby 2.2.2 using RVM

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I ran `rvm -v` and it returned `rvm 1.29.1` so I ran `rvm install 2.2.2` to upgrade the Ruby version.

It showed:

```
ruby-2.2.2 - #removing rubies/ruby-2.2.2..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.tar.bz2
ruby-2.2.2 - #configure
ruby-2.2.2 - #download
ruby-2.2.2 - #validate archive
ruby-2.2.2 - #extract
ruby-2.2.2 - #validate binary
ruby-2.2.2 - #setup
ruby-2.2.2 - #gemset created /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
ruby-2.2.2 - #importing gemset /usr/local/rvm/gemsets/global.gems...............
ruby-2.2.2 - #generating global wrappers........
ruby-2.2.2 - #gemset created /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
ruby-2.2.2 - #importing gemsetfile /usr/local/rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-2.2.2 - #generating default wrappers........
Making gemset ruby-2.2.2 pristine..............................................-
Making gemset ruby-2.2.2@global pristine.......................................|
```

I ran `rvm -v` again and it showed `rvm 1.29.1`. It means RVM did not install or did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Says you had 2.2.2 in the log!. Once installed you need to use it.

Comment: Why use 2.2.2? Current Ruby is 2.4. 2.3 would be a more appropriate version as it had worthwhile improvements.

Comment: I learn Ruby though Udemy. I just follow the instruction. I will use 2.4. 2.3 but not sure it will work.

Comment: How can you install ruby using "ruby" command and not "rvm", which doesn't exist in my system?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
$ rvm use 2.2.2
```

From: https://rvm.io/rvm/basics

Comment: Or better, `rvm use 2.2.2 --default` to tell RVM to remember that setting.

Comment: Okay - I ran both `rvm use 2.2.2` and `rvm use 2.2.2 --default`. I still got the same output `rvm 1.29.1 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io/]`

Comment: Yes, that's your `rvm` version, which is current. `ruby -v` will tell you your ruby version, as DannyD's answer states. BTW, we use version managers b/c versions change, and different projects use different versions. It's a way to keep different ruby "containers" separate from each other. So, when you specify the `rvm use <version_number> --default` that's setting the version for everywhere on your system, if you just use `rvm use <version_number>` it will set it in that local directory, so you can run it specifically for that project. :-)

Comment: I got it works by run `rvm remove rbx-2.2.2` and then run `ruby-install --latest ruby`, not sure why it works!

Comment: Well, to be honest, I use `rbenv` to manage my ruby versions. [see here.](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) And, `ruby-install` is a different command, that I believe comes from a different tech called `'ruby-install'` [see here.](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) So, if it's working great, but if it's a requirement that you get your ruby version installed with `rvm`, you might want to look into that....

Answer (score 6):

RVM and ruby are two different things.

You are running RVM -v to get the ruby version when you should be doing

```
ruby -v
```

To answer the question to install using rvm

```
rvm install <version>
rvm use <version>
ruby -v
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this on CentOS 6.5:

1. Update the key using gpg (see here https://rvm.io/rvm/install)
2. Install rvm: `curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
3. Install ruby: `rvm install ruby-2.2.2`